# How do you prevent browser caching when polling based on last-modified header?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

```
function sendReq(){
  fetch('query.json').then(res=>{
    if(res.headers.get('Last-Modified')!=lastMod){
      lastMod=res.headers.get('Last-Modified');
      res.json().then(j=>update(j));
    }
  })
}
setInterval(sendReq,2e3);
```

So as you can see in my code I'm polling a json file every two seconds. I check the last-modified header to see if it is different then the last one I have and if so I update accordingly. The problem is in firebug it doesn't even show the requests being sent out. So I assume it is merely serving the file from the browser cache. I can add a timestamp to the request so `fetch('query.json?t='+(+new Date()))`, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

I may be misunderstanding how this works, but I think I still want the If-Modified-Since header being sent since that is what I'm interested in anyways. But if I'm adding a timestamp the whole file is sent every time.

Comment: If you don't see the request in the net-tab then it's not made. You should see a request with a **304 not modified** result or _from cache_ or something similar.

Comment: It was doing that then stopped. I may need to restart my browser. But I can log the request every 2 seconds and from that it says nothing is updating either.

Comment: What other headers are in the reply? Possible some headers that influence caching.

Comment: How do you get all headers from a fetch request since you have to provide the id to the .get method?

Comment: Look in the Firebug net tab.

Comment: I tried it on a different computer and firebug isn't showing the requests in the net-panel. I did check Firefox's console and it shows request headers for: Host, User-Agent, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Origin, Referer, and Connection. Connection is set to `keep-alive`