# In a new Header why does Firefox add headers when initatiating with if-modified-since?

Tags: javascript, http-headers

In working with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981892/how-do-you-prevent-browser-caching-when-polling-based-on-last-modified-header) I realized that if I set the `if-modified-since` header (I haven't found any other headers that do this)

```
fetch('query.json',
  {headers:new Headers({'If-Modified-Since':lastMod})
})
```

The request headers set `cache-control` and `pragma` to `no-cache`. I tried explicitly setting them, but Firefox still tacked `, no-cache` on the end. I tried deleting them, but that didn't work either. I checked and Chrome sets `cache-control` to 'max-age=0', but I am able to clear that header. I'm using Firefox 49.0.1. I realize that Headers is an experimental technology, but why behind the scenes does Firefox on this one header add two extra headers and is there any way around it?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you don't have any settings in Firefox to disable caching?

Comment: Pretty sure, plus if I remove the `if-modified-since` it doesn't send the `no-cache`